# How to apply linear regression model only when a certain condition of a input column is met?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My train data set has following attributes:

cost, clicks, impressions, conversions, adgroup

I created a linear regression model to predict 'revenue'

Now, I want to modify my model so that I get output from linear regression only when the attribute 'conversions' value is not 0, and if the attribute 'conversions' is 0 then to get the output directly as 0.

What I did was that on train dataset I directly formed the following model

```
input_cols = ['clicks', 'impressions', 'cost', 'conversions', 'adgroup 1', 'adgroup 2', 'adgroup 3', 'adgroup 4']
inputs, targets = train_csv[input_cols], train_csv['revenue']
model = LinearRegression().fit(inputs, targets)
```

After That, in test data set I did the following to get 0 whenever 'conversions' is 0

```
input_cols_test= ['clicks', 'impressions', 'cost', 'conversions', 'adgroup 1', 'adgroup 2', 'adgroup 3', 'adgroup 4']
inputs_test= test_csv[input_cols_test]
targets=[]
for n in test_csv['conversions']:
     if n == 0:
           targets = 0
     else:
           targets = (model.predict(inputs_test))
```

But the targets array that I am getting has values that are got from the linear regression. I am not getting 0 as output at places where 'conversions' is 0. How to deal with this?

Comment: Why you define `input_cols_test` while never using it? Plus, please change the quotes in your 2nd code snippet (they should not be *inverse* quotes).

Comment: `targets = (model.predict(inputs_test))` just predicts the whole `inputs_test`  dataset, and overwrites whatever value was in `targets` before. This is not what you want to do - you want to predict a *single* row there, and to *append* (not rewrite) `targets` in each loop execution.